# How to run automatically executable from CLI using lldb?

Tags: lldb, command-line

In `gdb`, I can run automatically the binary as (as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119564/55075)):

```
gdb -ex run /bin/true
```

What's the equivalent parameter for `lldb`?

This works:

```
echo run | lldb /bin/true
```

but I'd like to back to debugger console instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LLDB >= 3.4 has the `-o` / `--one-line` command line option that can be used to launch your program automatically:

`lldb -o run /bin/true`

For reference here are two relevant snippets from `lldb-3.6 --help`:

```
...
   -o 
   --one-line 
        Tells the debugger to execute this one-line lldb command
        after any file provided on the command line has been loaded.
...
  Notes:

       Multiple "-s" and "-o" options can be provided.  They will be
       processed from left to right in order, with the source files 
       and commands interleaved. 
...
```

And for reviewing command line options in a web browser -- here's a link to the [lldb-3.4 man page](https://www.netsoup.net/docs/man/lldb-3.4).

Note that with LLDB < 3.4 (and also newer versions) you can use the `-s` / `--source` option to bootstrap commands like `run` -- for example:

```
$ echo run > autorun
$ lldb -s autorun -- /bin/echo arg1 arg2
```

Comment: When running using `-o run` instead of manually entering `run` in LLDB console it is not possible to interrupt the process using Ctrl-C. Is there any way to fix that?